# Transparent STATIC text changing

Tags: c++

I have this STATIC control displayed over a window that has an image as its background. When I initiate the control it displays a text. If I want to change the text inside a WM_TIMER message it is displayed over the initial text (it is not removed) I have tried UpdateWindow and InvalidateRect but id doesn't work.
This is my code

```
WM_CREATE:
    HWND control = CreateWindowEx(
                                 WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
                                 L"STATIC",
                                 L"FirstText",
                                 WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_LEFT,
                                 0,
                                 0,
                                 200,
                                 20,
                                 hWnd,
                                 HMENU(LABEL1),
                                 Instance,
                                 NULL
                                 );
break;
case WM_TIMER:
    SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, LABEL1), L"SecondText");
    KillTimer(hWnd, MYTIMER);
    // Here I tried UpdateWindow and InvalidateRect but no result
break;
```

So, the second text is drawn over the first one. It looks like the STATIC content is not updated after changing it. What could be going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hard coded some numbers in there for testing (like the window ID) - but it's just an example to show you.

```
case WM_CREATE:
        control = CreateWindowEx(
            WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,
            L"STATIC",
            L"FirstText",
            WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_LEFT,
            0,
            0,
            200,
            20,
            hWnd,
            HMENU(99),
            hInst,
            NULL
            );

    //Create a timer
      SetTimer(hWnd,23, 5000,NULL);  
        break;

    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:

        if ( GetDlgItem(hWnd, 99) == (HWND)lParam)
        {
            SetBkMode( (HDC)wParam, TRANSPARENT);
             return (LRESULT) GetStockObject(HOLLOW_BRUSH);
       }
            break;

    case WM_TIMER:
        {
            SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(hWnd, 99), L"Second Text");
            KillTimer(hWnd, 23);


            RECT rect = {0,0, 200,20};
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect, TRUE);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        }
        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        //Load my test bitmap from resources
        HBITMAP hb = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1));
        BITMAP bm;
        GetObject(hb, sizeof(BITMAP), &bm);
        HDC memDC= CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(memDC,hb); 


        // ========================
        //Put the bitmap on the main window to act as a backdrop
        BitBlt(hdc, 0,0, bm.bmWidth,bm.bmHeight,memDC,0,0, SRCCOPY);
        DeleteDC(memDC);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
```